# D-Link Ethernet PCI Card DGE-528T

Tags: networking, ethernet

Since my built-in Ethernet port fail to acces the internet, I decided to buy and install a brand new D-Link Ethernet PCI Card DGE-528T.

On one side I can access lots of web sites and on the other side, there are web sites that my Power Mac G5 seems to not access. I don't know why.

What are the commands lines in Terminal to tell my computer to use only the PCI Ethernet port instead of the built-in Ethernet port?

Thanks for your answers.

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

If the on-board network port is unplugged and your PCI network card is installed correctly you should not be encountering a problem. 
Ensure that you've removed the Ethernet cable from the on-board port. 
Since you no longer need the on-board port, it may be simpler to just delete it. See below

https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=26681
(the on-board port should be the on that is Disconnected)

If you are still having trouble, and you are using a brand new network card then the problem may be with your router, motherboard, or Operating system installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Since I can't access my motherboard because of the processors above them, it's impossible for me to physically unplug the Ethernet cable. But, my Network settings are good according to me.